# Lost weather "widget" after factory reset

Tags: home-screen, google-pixel

I was having some hardware trouble with my Pixel (not resolved, but that's another issue). I ended up doing a factory reset.

Now, however, my home screen time/weather information. Instead of the date, time and (when available) weather showing at the top of the first screen with an abbreviated search field (see image below)

[image: Pixel home screen]

The above is what it *should* look like. Now, that "widget" is gone, and the search field takes up the whole top line of the screen.

There are no updates for the Pixel Launcher for me in the Play Store (and, in fact, no buttons to go with it).

I've tried force-stopping the Pixel Launcher app.

If there's a setting for this I can't find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read this : http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/03/29/new-pixel-launcher-design-showing-users/

Comment: @Six: I think that's probably it.

Comment: Oh! I stand corrected. I finally found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the steps from [Scrapshark's reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/58k5eq/psa_how_to_enable_the_weather_indicator_widget/d915a4o/)?

[image]

Also, I'm reading that this problem could be the result of the Pixel launcher losing its location permission, so you should check if it still has that by following the steps in [Google's help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602) under the section called `Turn permissions on or off`.

Comment: Clearing all of the app data fixed it for me (although it cleared all of my restored app icons). I think what was throwing me is that the "Clear Data" button is buried a little further in the app settings than it used to be.